# Change Domain name in database

Tags: database, domain

I got a bug after change domain name in database.
My first domain name was : http://test.website1.io 
Then I want to change it to yoonaa.com
so I use phpmyadmin, access to wp-options table, then change siteurl and home to yoonaa.com.

after a while yoonaa.com works, but yoonaa.com/wp-admin doesn't work. http://test.website1.io/wp-admin still works.

Please help me if you have experienced this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Is this perhaps a WordPress Multisite?

Comment: @Yoona, Could you please let us know if this a multi-site or a simple wordpress site

Comment: Hi, it is a single site. I fixed it by add www. It was my mistake. Thanks a lot.